# pickerView shows up as question marks instead of data?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6

I am trying to add a pickerview to my iphone application but instead of showing string from my array it shows question marks. Does anyone know why? I've been trying to figure it out for the past hour... Here is my code of the controller that contains the pickerview:

```
class NewIssueViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var componentArr = ["component1","component2","component3","component4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func CancelPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func AddPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return componentArr.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return componentArr[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You set your picker view's datasource, but didn't set its delegate.

As a result `pickerView:titleForRow:` never gets called.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to set the delegate, see this image: http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52428a0ae4b0c4a5c2a2cede/t/543c1649e4b095b4c24a3d3c/1413224010678/dataSource-delegate.png?format=750w

Comment: or add `self.YourIBOutletForPicker.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

You should either connect the `PickerView`'s  `Datasource` and `Delegate` in the storyboard or set them programatically. See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New Swift 3 has deprecated usage of above methods,

i have implemented the following to make them work. (Some underscore added in param.

```
 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    /*if(row == 0)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    }
    else if(row == 1)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    }
    else if(row == 2)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.greenColor();
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **self.pickerOutletReference.delegate = self** on viewDidLoad() menthod