# Picker View is show character "?" instead of item name?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, uipickerview

I have problem with hospital ViewPicker. when the user click on text field hospitalName to select hospital name from viewPicker the item is show character "?" instead of item name I have attach Image
Note I use same logic for location text field

[image]

```
  class VisitsViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

        //MARK -
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(BrnViewController.dismissKeybored)))       
            self.pickerLocation.dataSource = self
            self.pickerLocation.delegate  = self
            self.pickerLocation.tag = 1
            self.pickerHospital.dataSource  = self
            self.pickerHospital.dataSource = self
            self.pickerHospital.tag = 2

            visitLocationTextField.inputView = pickerLocation
            self.visitLocationTextField.delegate = self        
            hospitalNameTextField.inputView = pickerHospital 
            self.hospitalNameTextField.delegate = self
        }

            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        // MARK: - Picker View
        func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            if pickerView.tag == 1 {
              return pickerDataVisitLocation.count
            }
            else{
                return pickerDataHospitalName.count
            }
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
            if pickerView.tag == 1{
                visitLocationTextField.text = pickerDataVisitLocation[row]
            }
            else{
                HospitalNameTextField.text = pickerDataHospitalName[row]
            }
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)-> String? {
            if pickerView.tag == 1{
            return pickerDataVisitLocation[row]
            }
            else{
                return pickerDataHospitalName[row]
            }
        }
           //MARK: - @IBOutlet
        @IBOutlet weak var visitLocationTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var hospitalNameTextField: UITextField!

            //MARK: - variables
        var pickerDataVisitLocation = [" ","Home","Hospital","Other"]
        var pickerDataHospitalName = [" ","test1","test2","test3"]
        var pickerLocation  = UIPickerView()
        var pickerHospital =  UIPickerView()
    }
```

Comment: Add a print in `titleForRow`; does it print the right string? Is that string an optional?

Comment: i noticed you have      self.pickerHospital.dataSource  = self set twice. Can you delete one of these lines and to see if that was causing the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pickerView shows up as question marks instead of data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747115/pickerview-shows-up-as-question-marks-instead-of-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set pickerHospital delegate. Replicated `self.pickerHospital.dataSource = self` two times. You should have wrote:

```
self.pickerHospital.dataSource = self
self.pickerHospital.delegate = self
```